# Absolutely Position a Cloned Element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, clone, absolute

I'm trying to absolutely position a cloned div with jQuery.  When I add CSS to the cloned element with the .css() method it only moves the text (even if I copy all of parent element's CSS into this object.

I have a fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/emilychews/xuup6va1/3/

If you click on the blue div it creates a clone.

For quick reference the code is :

```js
$('#testdiv').click(function() {
  $(this).clone()
    .insertAfter('#testdiv');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#testdiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="testdiv">
    <h1>I am a div</h1>
    <p>with a blue background</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like  `$( this ).clone()  .insertAfter('#testdiv').css("position","absolute").css("left","200px");`

Comment: Where do you want your clone postioned?

Comment: Yes, mgrsskls's answer worked.  I don't know why this didn't work when I originally did it.  I'm going to go back to codepen from jsfiddle I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me if I do this:

```
$('#testdiv').click(function() {
  $( this ).clone()
    .insertAfter('#testdiv')
    .css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0
    });
});
```

But be aware that your element has an ID. So, if you clone id, you create invalid markup.

Comment: I don't know why that wasn't working that was the exact code I did.

Comment: Changed id testdiv to a class and added a left property to make the cloned div more obvious. https://jsfiddle.net/xuup6va1/4/ Emily, your code might have been working with the cloned div being placed directly on top of the original.